# Emacs Not Responding on launch on Mac OS X

Tags: init-file

My Emacs 24.5.1 is not responding frequently recently on my MacBook Pro Yosemite 10.10.3. I have installed it from [emacs for mac osx](http://emacsformacosx.com). Emacs window does not open, it shows Not Responding in the Activity Monitor. Sometimes it launches successfully without all these symptoms.

What can be the reason for this? Is the latest version of the Emacs is buggy for mac or there is a different known reason for that?

Comment: I see similar problems when the system is starting up.  Waiting until initial background processes have completed before launching emacs helps, but it is hard to diagnose exactly.

Comment: in my case it is not after the system start up necessarily.

Comment: occasionally I have temporal "not responding" issues when opening files or show the content of a subtree in org-mode, I can't figure out why. I am using Emacs 25.0, plan to upgrade it to the newest version to see if I can get rid of the problem.

Comment: is emacs doing something at startup that is trying to show you a dialog box?  I (and many others it seems) have issues with emacs freezing completely when it tries to present a dialog box.

Comment: no, it does not.

Comment: Are you by any chance one of those people who never ever reboot their computer and just put it in sleep mode (by closing the lid) and expect it to work perfectly day after day, month after month, year after year?  :)  What other programs do you have running that might be causing some sort of a conflict?  Have you gone through the startup and removed programs that load automatically to try and reduce the possibility of conflicts -- System Preferences/Accounts/Login Items?  Are you running Emacs in `daemon` mode?  Any other details you can provide regarding your setup that might give us a clue?

Comment: Yes I am the chief of the noreboot Republic. Yes I have team viewer and better touch tool as login items. Other things I will monitor. :)

Comment: I do not think I am using emacs in demon mode. How can I be sure?

Comment: `daemon` is for people who want lightening fast startup and they usually call `emacsclient` from the terminal, which connects to a running instance of Emacs.  If you haven't gone out of your way to specifically set that up, then you can eliminate that as a potential suspect.

Comment: Ok. I see. I did not set emacs server, or use emacs client.

Comment: When it stucked it comes to use only 12 MBs of memory. While this happens I was just using e. 3.5 of 4 MBs of ram. I think it uses normally 30MBs of memory.

Comment: I have now closed safari. I am using 1.8 Mrs of 4 Mrs ram, I have clicked emacs and it have successfully launched. Several times I have quit and launch, with some files sometimes, no problem. It uses 30 MBs memory after just launched successfully, and now.

Comment: Just shutdown your Mac and reboot. The Emacs "not responding" problem will go away.

Comment: @Goh: This will not work in for a buggy version of emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem in the current release of Emacs. It is fixed in the upcoming release of Emacs 25.

The underlying cause is that input events started to arrive before the initialization code was done.

The problems were more prominent when the system was low on resources or when under heavy load, e.g. when Emacs was launched at system startup.